# bootstrap only one column on mobile screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a logo assemble similar to another website. On mobile screen the logo's reduce from eight a row to four on each row as shown below. My code is in a bootstrap container.

**On Desktop**
[image]

**On Mobile**

[image]

Mine works fine on desktop, but when it reaches small size it suddenly goes in one row only.

**My site on Desktop**
[image]

**My site on Mobile**

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5 text-center align-items-center">
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-xs-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-xs-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-xs-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-xs-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-xs-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-xs-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-xs-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-xs-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-xs-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-xs-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-xs-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-xs-3"><img src="..."></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to have at least 2-3 logos in one row on a mobile screen.

Comment: What's `xm`? That is not a Bootstrap breakpoint. Please [read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#responsive-classes). You should be using `col-3` not `col-xm-3`.

Comment: That's a typo, I edited it, but it doesn't make a difference on the outcome

Comment: Again, did you read the docs? There is no col-xs-3 in Bootstrap any longer. It's just col-3 because mobile (xs) is the default implied breakpoint

Comment: I changed it to col-3 and it worked, thank you. It's weird because i've been seeing 
 (xs) everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5 text-center align-items-center">
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2  col-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2  col-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2  col-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2  col-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2 col-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2  col-3"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="mb-4 col-md-2  col-3"><img src="..."></div>
    </div>
</div>

You should do like the comments. I tried and worked fine for me.
```

Comment: If this is an answer you have come up with, please explain how this solves the problem. Comments already explained and fixed the issue OP had.

Comment: That's because he wrote this before "That's a typo, I edited it, but it doesn't make a difference on the outcome " I thought he couldn't do it so I did and said it worked for me. I never implemented that I found this solution. I am sorry if I did something wrong btw.

Comment: No, you didn't do anything wrong. It answers the question. But it doesn't clearly explain how it fixes the issue. Please consider adding some explanation, credit to the user who commented the fix and link to official documentation, so future readers get a clear answer. Most people wouldn't read comments. Answers that are not accepted are more likely to be read by users than answer in the comments.